# SwiftにてModel(struct)をUserDefaultsで保存したい

Tags: swift

SwiftにてMVVMの`Model`を`struct`で作成して、そのModelを`UserDefaults`で保存したいのですが、structは継承ができず、普通に実装するとModelをclassにしないといけません。そこで以下記事のようにstructの中に`HelperClass`を作成してそのHelperClassにNSObjectを継承させ、UserDefaultsで扱えるようにする方法があるようですが、これは賢い方法ですか？それとも普通にModelをclassにしたほうがいいのでしょうか？

https://swiftandpainless.com/nscoding-and-swift-structs/

Comment: 目的は「NSObjectを継承させ」ることですか？それとも「`UserDefaults`で保存」することですか？

Comment: UserDefaultsで保存が目的ですね。タイトルを修正します。

Comment: 「UserDefaultsで保存」が目的なら、そもそも現在のSwiftで実装するならstructをCodableにするのが常道でしょう。あとはそのstructの中身がわからないとなんとも言えないところですが、本当にUserDefaultsに保存してもいいような小さなModelなんでしょうか?

Comment: 目的と手段が入れ替わって？しまい調べ方がおかしかったようです。Codableを使えば簡単に実装できるのですね。例としてあげたのでModelの大きさは考慮していませんでしたが、UserDefaultsには小さいModelを保存する予定です。

Comment: 丁寧なご返信ありがとうございます。Codableを使ってうまく行った場合、概要だけでも十分だと思いますので、ぜひ自己回答してみてください。その方向性で何かつまづいた場合には、ご質問に追記などしていただければお手伝いできることがあるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`struct`を保存するには`JSONEncoder`と`Codable`を使って`UserDefaults`に保存するのが一般的のようです。
https://enmtknt.hateblo.jp/entry/2018/07/17/161915